# Android App crashes on while()

Tags: java, android, sockets, bufferedreader

In my android app I'm creating a Socket and a BufferedReader. If i just read one line of the BufferedReader I'm getting the response from the server. But if I'm trying it with `while((message = br.readLine()) != null)` The application crashes. Any ideas what could be the problem?

#### Code

```
public void connecting(String uid) {
    uuid = uid;
    try {
        client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8234);
        try {
            tv = (TextView) chat.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // If i just try this, it works
                        tv.append("\n"+br.readLine());

                        // If I'm trying this, it crashes
                        String message = "";
                        while((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            tv.append("\n"+message);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        tv.append(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            tv.append("Connected!");
            pw.println(uuid+":B31TR1TT");
            pw.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            tv.append(e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        tv.append(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: Post the error message or logcat

Comment: Please edit your code properly. Put at least 4 white-spaces before every line of the code and then see the magic of markdown.

Comment: Most likely, you have at some point `br` in `br.readLine()` being `null`. Post your logcat please.

Comment: LogCat: http://hastebin.com/wapocuguwu.avrasm

Comment: It seems you have `StritcMode` enabled: `StrictMode policy violation;`. Try to disable it and see if that is the problem: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Comment: Seems like a better idea to fix the problem that StrictMode is complaining about rather than disabling StrictMode.

Comment: I'm using this: ´StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());`

Comment: @Michael, Yes, it was only to see if it was the problem :-)

Comment: Are you calling `connecting` on the main thread? If so, you should probably make sure that you don't do that. And what's `de.Timpa.mCyber.Check.connect`? It's listed in your stacktrace, but I don't see the code for that in your question.

Comment: You should put your networks operations in a separated thread, not in the ui thread. Maybe that is why you get the error.

Comment: [at]Michael connecting() is the connect() method, just renamed it and changed IP...  

@algui91 You mean a single class implementing Runnable?

Comment: Conversely, you should only update the UI from the UI thread. So you shouldn't do `tv.append` from the new thread that you spawn. Find a way to pass the new text to some code that runs on the UI thread, e.g. through a `Handler`.

Comment: Or with a `AsyncTask`, you could do your network operations and in the `onPostExecute` update your UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As algui91 said move the network calls to a separate thread. that strict mode error (violation=4) indicates network calls on ui thread.

Just refactor the network calls into a background task (service, asynctask , or whaetever ) , and the issue should go away.

Separate the UI from the business logic or network communication. Its always better and easier to test/debug.

Answer (score -2):

`ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = 
                  new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
             while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                 byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                 response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
             }`

Instead of while loop code try to use this code
or visit this link http://hastebin.com/inecerakes.java

Comment: What does this have to do with the StrictMode policy violation?

Comment: Ooh. sorry as per your log cat you need to use Strict Mode.